# What does new char(size) mean in C++?

Tags: c++

While allocating a buffer via `new` (in C++) I mistakenly wrote:

```
int size = 1024 * 1024;
char *buf = new char(size);
```

instead of the normal syntax

```
char *buf = new char[size];
```

However the code did get compiled and led to strange crashes when using this `buf` variable. Apparently it seems that a buffer of eight bytes was allocated.

I would like to know the meaning of `new char(size)`.

Comment: A single char initialized with the value of size (which probably won´t fit into it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *buf = new char(size);
```

It allocates only `sizeof(char)` bytes and initializes it with `size` — *loosely* equivalent to this:

```
char *__internal_buf = new char; //1 byte only

*__internal_buf = size; //or static_cast<char>(size);

 char *buf = __internal_buf;
```

It is the same difference as in these two:

```
 char x(65);  //y is single element initialized to be 'A'. as 65 is 'A'
 char y[65];  //y is an array of size 65
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `new char` allocates scalar `char`. `new char[1]` allocates vector `char`

Answer (score 4):

It means you allocate memory for a single `char` and initialize it with the integer `size`. In your case, `size` doesn't fit into a `char`. If the `char` happens to be signed, then the integer `size` is being converted into a `char`, but the results are implementation-defined. If the `char` is `unsigned`, then the `int` wraps around the maximum value represented by the `char` (typically 255).

A similar syntax exists also for non-pointers:

```
int x(10); // initialize x with 10
```

or

```
char c('a'); // initializes c with 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Null, but here's a better example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size = 'A';
    char *buf = new char(size);

    cout << *buf;
}
```

Prints out A

Reason for NULL: 1024*1024 = 0x100000. The last byte goes in the char. Char is Null. Least efficient null terminated string I've seen in a while, in fact.